# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buenas tardes realizo una interfaz en la cual se puedan importar datos desde un Excel (.CSV) pero quiero insertar mas de 10,000 datos pero me sale este error Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in functions.php on line 6

```html
<?php

 function insertar_datos($id_Control,$Fecha,$Hora){
   global $conexion;
  $sentencia = "insert into reloj (id_Control,Fecha,Hora) values ('$id_Control','$Fecha','$Hora')";
  $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion,$sentencia);
 
  return $ejecutar;
 }
?>
```

Anexo el código del formulario para subirlo a la BD

```html
<?php

if (isset($_POST["enviar"])) {//nos permite recepcionar una variable que si exista y que no sea null
 require_once("conexion_excel.php");
 require_once("functions.php");
 $archivo = $_FILES["archivo"]["name"];
 $archivo_copiado= $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"];
 $archivo_guardado = "copia_".$archivo;

 //echo $archivo."esta en la ruta temporal: " .$archivo_copiado;

 if (copy($archivo_copiado ,$archivo_guardado )) {
  //echo "se copeo correctamente el archivo temporal a nuestra carpeta de trabajo <br/>";
 }else{
  //echo "hubo un error <br/>";
 }
    
    if (file_exists($archivo_guardado)) {
      
      $fp = fopen($archivo_guardado,"r");//abrir un archivo
         $rows = 0;
         while ($datos = fgetcsv($fp , 7000 , ";")) {
              $rows ++;
             // echo $datos[0] ." ".$datos[1] ." ".$datos[2]." ".$datos[3] ."<br/>";
          if ($rows > 1) {
           $resultado = insertar_datos($datos[0],$datos[1],$datos[2]);
          if($resultado){
           //echo "se inserto los datos correctamente<br/>";
          }else{
           //echo "no se inserto <br/>";
          }
          }
         }



    }else{
     echo "No existe el archivo copiado <br/>";
    }

}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay 2 formas de hacerlo pero eso depende del tipo de servidor que se tenga. Si tienes acceso al PHP.ini puedes hacerlo desde ahí modificando esta linea.
`max_execution_time=30` en donde 30 es la cantidad de segundos que quieres configurar para que se siga ejecutando una tarea.

O puedes hacerlo al inicio de la función utilizando uno de estos 2 comandos.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '300');
set_time_limit(300);
```

Por supuesto si haces cambios en el PHP.ini debes hacerlo siempre con cuidado y reiniciar apache para que tome los cambios.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya no me marca el error, solo que ahora no me inserta los primero 1,500 registros en el campo de hora y en mi campo de fecha solo me aparecen 0000-00-00.

Answer (score 0):

Abundando en la respuesta de [Raul A.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/74051/raul-a), la manera correcta, si es que el ambiente donde estás corriendo te lo permite, sería usar [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/es/function.set-time-limit.php). Sin embargo, al inicio del proceso no sabes cuánto tardará exactamente, por lo que estimar 300, 600 o 900 segundos eventualmente puede llevarte a un caso de borde.

Me parecería más correcto que en cada iteración fueras llamando nuevamente a `set_time_limit`.

```
while ($datos = fgetcsv($fp , 7000 , ";")) {
  set_time_limit(300);
  // código de inserción
}
```

Con eso, por cada registro extiendes el tiempo de expiración a 30 segundos  a partir de ese momento.